# Unable to specify the name of an index for a secondary table with DataNucleus

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I've got the following JDO class that I'm trying to use with DataNucleus `4.1.0-release`:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "accounts", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public final class Account {
    @Persistent(primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Column(allowsNull = "false")
    private long id;

    // A Set of enum constants.
    @Persistent(table = "account_roles")
    @Join(column = "account_id", primaryKey = "account_roles_account_id_role_pkey", foreignKey = "account_roles_account_id_fkey", index = "account_roles_account_id_idx")
    @Element(column = "role")
    private Set<SecurityRole> roles;
}
```

Running schema generation for this table against PostgreSQL gives me the following, though:

```
-- Table "accounts" for classes [com.trickle.api.accounts.Account]
CREATE TABLE "accounts"
(
    "id" SERIAL,
    CONSTRAINT "accounts_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- Table "account_roles" for join relationship
CREATE TABLE "account_roles"
(
    "account_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "role" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "account_roles_account_id_role_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("account_id","role")
);

-- Constraints for table "accounts" for class(es) [com.trickle.api.accounts.Account]

-- Constraints for table "account_roles"
ALTER TABLE "account_roles" ADD CONSTRAINT "account_roles_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("account_id") REFERENCES "accounts" ("id") INITIALLY DEFERRED ;

CREATE INDEX "account_roles_N49" ON "account_roles" ("account_id");
```

Note the index name of "`account_roles_N49`", instead of the "`account_roles_account_id_idx`" that I'd specified in the class' annotation. What am I doing wrong here?